# 404 Error handling for subdomains rewriteRule

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, error-handling, dns

In case of a non existing page I have an Error 404 Document. Now I recognized that the whole thing works only for the Domain but not for Subdomains. There is just one Subdomain that is supported by that 404 Error handling. This Subdomain is `www` so in case of `www.example.com/...` it works like for `example.com/...`.

If the Subdomain is not `www` i.e. `xyz.example.com/...` it does not work. So I would like to have a RewriteRule that rewrites everything that is not `www` into `www`. Is it possible to do this case sensitive, means that this condition only works for all Subdomains except that ones that are existing? At the moment there are no Subdomains but they are planed for the future.

It would be nice if someone could give me hints to solve this issue. I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hello and thanks. i tried this. it will add 'www.' in front of a wrong subdomain. it will be: 'www.wiw.example.com...'

Comment: hello, did you changed something? it still does not work. i used your code, but the result is like what i have answered before.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this-

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://foo.example.com/cgi-bin/tester
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription_info.html
ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry can't allow you access today"
```

You can get more info on [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) site.

Comment: have a look at the question and the problem. i asked for a rewrite rule and not for a redirect to another file.

Comment: You can add this in your htaccess file with path to 404 error file and create on html file so that error will get displayed. Just have a look at the Apache link. you will have a better idea.

Comment: this is not the main goal?! why should i spend time with something that is not wished to. sorry, but this not seems logical to me. the answer of Prasath Albert is what i would like to archieve.